# Сохранить данные в переменую из запроса в MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

подскажите как можно сохранить данные в переменную после запроса в MongoDB. Использую библиотеку mongoose.
Пример:

```
const findAdressDB = () => {
    let result = {}
    Adress.findOne({ street: 'Омская' }).exec()
        .then(req => {
            console.log(req) //Здесь выдает результат запроса
            result.street = req.street // пропускает из за асинхронности
        })
    return result
}
```

Пытался переписать с async/await результат тот же. Получилось только с использованием express, но мне неподходит (app.get('/' (req res)).

Answer (score 0):

> Пытался переписать с async/await результат тот же.

Так смотря что ты делал и как использовал...

```
const findAdressDB = async () => {
    let result = await Adress.findOne({ street: 'Омская' }).exec()
    console.log(result) 
    result.street = req.street 
    return result
}
// использование
findAdressDB()
    .then(res => {
        // вот тут будет ответ
        console.log(res) 
    })
```

Comment: Мне нужно ответ который приходит после запроса в БД сохранить в свой объект. После его использовать в другой части кода. Как ты предложил я побывал. Где ты написал использование надо сохранить часть ответа в другой объект. Из за того что операция асинхронная он пропускает.

Comment: @sinner, для более детального ответа нужно задавать более детальные вопросы... ;)

Comment: Всю голову "сломал", уже пробовал через cursor, эффект такой же. Есть идей?

Comment: @sinner, я ведь не в курсе что ты собрался делать...

Comment: Идея простая, сделать запрос в базу. Ответ придет виде объекта. Отдельное поле сохранить в другой объект. Вот и все что я хочу )))

Comment: @sinner, так я тебе показал как можно получить ответ на запрос... Далее в `.then()` ты можешь выполнять любые синхронные действия с ответом.

Comment: let temp = {}
findAdressDB()
    .then(res => {
        temp.street = res.street
        console.log(res) 
    })

Comment: Сори не могу отформатировать (( В переменной не сохраняется, он остается пустым.

Comment: @sinner, так ты свой вопрос редактируй - там все это можно проделать без проблем. ;)

Comment: @sinner, вроде ничего "криминального" в твоем последнем варианте нет... Вполне рабочий код.

Comment: Но не сохраняет, я так думаю что запрос в БД занимает время, и он сохраняет в объект пустоту и после мне в консоль выводится ответ. Как я не пытался не могу заставить дождаться ответа сохранить и дальше продолжить выполнять скрипт.

Comment: @sinner, еще раз повторюсь - я не в курсе что ты там вообще делаешь. Естественно что ответ по запросу асинхронен. Результат придет в `.then()` - именно там и нужно делать все (!) синхронные действия.

Comment: Вроде понял, как с запросами работать. Нужно в then  вызывать функцию и в нее передавать значение и там уже обрабатывать.

Comment: @sinner, можно функцию вызвать... Можно и так некие действия выполнить... Можно далее продолжить асинхронную цепочку... Т.е. все действия выполняются когда обещание (промис) завершилось. Так же нужно понимать что обещание может завершиться и ошибкой. Ее нужно так же обработать. ;)